# Python function not writing or overwriting when threading

Tags: python

I have a script that takes a a group of images on the local machine, sends it to removeBG using threading.  If it is successful, it gets the resultant file and uploads to s3 and grabs the s3 URL.  Now we pass this URL to BannerBear to generate a composite which returns another URL that we print to the screen and then get the file so we can write it locally.

But while all the text of each process is being printed to the screen properly, somewhere along the way the writing of the final image locally gets skipped or overwritten by the other file that is being processed.  If I go one at a time it works.

**Code:**

```
# Check the result of the RemoveBG API request if ok write the file locally and upload to s3
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open(
        os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".png"), "wb"
    ) as out:
        out.write(response.content)

        # Open a file-like object using io.BytesIO
        image_data = io.BytesIO(response.content)

        # Upload the image data to S3
        s3.upload_fileobj(image_data, bucket_name, object_key)

        # Get the URL for the uploaded image
        image_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{object_key}"
        print(f"Image uploaded to S3: {image_url}")

        # pass the s3 url to BannerBear
        bannerbear(image_url)


# start BannerBear Func
def bannerbear(photo_url):

    # Send a POST request to the endpoint URL
    responseBB = requests.post(endpoint_url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if responseBB.status_code == 200:
        # Print the URL of the generated image
        print(responseBB.json()["image_url_jpg"])
        # Write the image data to a file
        filedata = requests.get(responseBB.json()["image_url_jpg"])
        with open(
            os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, "bb", os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".jpg"), "wb"
        ) as f:
            f.write(filedata.content)
        print("BannerBear File Written")
    else:
        # Something went wrong
        print(f"An error occurred: {responseBB.status_code}")
        print(response.json()["message"])


# Create a thread pool with a maximum of 4 threads
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    # Iterate through all the files in the image directory
    for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR):
        # Check if the file is an image
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png"):
            # Submit the task to the thread pool
            executor.submit(process_image, file)
```

This is what I see in the console:
So it's going through all the steps.
[image]

Comment: " writing of the final image locally gets skipped or overwritten" what do you mean by skipped are you getting any error?

Comment: not getting any errors and I just added the console output.  So it's executing each step.  But at the end of this process above with two images.  I would only end up with 1 bannerbear composite image written to the drive.

Comment: add a check whether you are getting the `filedata` or not

Comment: you are creating file name like this `os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, "bb", os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".jpg")` but i don't see any varaible named `file` in the `bannerbear` function

Comment: @deadshot that was it.. Thank you!  The file variable is setup globally by the thread executor.  So it has a file value set, and when I go to write image it's using another thread's file name.  I've changed it now to pass in the current working file name into the bannerbear function so we know what to name the file.  Thank you!!!